# Output single quotes in Razor generated JavaScript String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am assembling a few lines in JavaScript using Razor.  I thought the easiest way would be to assemble the entire JavaScript block first, then output the entire thing.  The problem is, the single quotes are being rendered as & #39;.

Is it possible to change the last line to get this to write correctly:

```
    var friendArray = new Array();
    @{
        int i = 0;
        string jsString="";
        foreach(var friend in friends)
        {
            jsString = jsString + "friendArray[";
            jsString = jsString + i.ToString();
            jsString = jsString + "]='";
            jsString = jsString + friend.displayname;
            jsString = jsString + "';";
            i++;
        }
        @jsString;
    }
```

The above generates this:

```
  friendArray[0]=& #39;Hollister& #39;;friendArray[1]=& #39;Festus& #39;;
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could turn off the encoding of HTML by outputting this way:

```
@Html.Raw(jsString)
```

Comment: That works.  Actually I tried it earlier, but I did not think I needed to prefix the @ so nothing wrote.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, without it you're in C#-mode, so the @ forces razor/html mode thus actually outputing the results.

Comment: This is a possible avenue for script injection if that jsString isn't trusted. Be very careful.

Comment: Not sure why (MVC 4?), but I had to do @Html.Raw(@Model.jsString) .

Comment: God knows how many times have I seen security holes like this one. Usually, an SO question gets upvoted like a cool one-liner, which obviously solves the issue, but also creates a security hole, which can later be easily exploited, without too much effort, if any. Please keep in mind to always sanitize your inputs AND your outputs (who knows which process persisted the info into your database and if it is safe to just print it to the end-user).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better solution would be to use JSON serializer, to sanitize your output, which obviously can present a possible injection security risk.

In your particular case, you would write this instead:

```
var friendArray = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(friends.Select(f => f.displayname)));
```

or if it's more readable to you this way:

```
    @{
        var arr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(friends.Select(f => f.displayname));
    }

    var friendArray = @Html.Raw(arr);
```

`arr` will be in the form of the JSON array, like `["a","b","c"]` and if you join that to your JS line, which creates the friendArray, you'll get something like: `var friendArray = ["a","b","c"];` which creates the same array like yours.

Do note that the semicolon (;) at the end of the `var friendArray` line is necessary to produce the valid JS statement.