# Escape character in MVC view JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page with this line:

```
  <input type="button" title="Join" value="Join" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to join @item.name.ToString() ?')) {location.href='@Url.Action("JoinTeam", "Team", new { id = item.id })'}" />&nbsp;
```

The `@item.name.ToString()` has a singe quote (`'`) in it and I need to escape it.

When I look at the raw HTML the `'` is `&#39`.

Comment: @item.name.ToString().Replace("'", @"\'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Json.Encode` to escape the special characters:

```
<input type="button" title="Join" value="Join" 
    onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to join @Json.Encode(item.name) ?')){location.href='@Url.Action("Home", "Index", new { id = item.id })'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731495/2477417) use `@Html.Raw(jsString)` in your case.

```
<input type="button" title="Join" value="Join" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to join @Html.Raw(item.name.ToString()) ?')) {location.href='@Url.Action("JoinTeam", "Team", new { id = item.id })'}" />&nbsp;
```